# Python: Import Slycot, symbol not found: _dgesv_

Tags: python, python-3.x, dylib

When trying to `import slycot`i get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/slycot/_wrapper.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _dgesv_

Referenced from: /Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/slycot/_wrapper.so

Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
```

Googling the last bit

```
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
```

results in loads of different software, and seems to be linked to a OSx problem. I always use pip to install python packages, and brew for other things.

---

```
which python

/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python

echo $PATH 

/Users/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/fsl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears due to conflict in the use of mkl libraries. _wrapper.so 
is compiled against anaconda's own mkl functions but on runtime its loading
mkl functions present on your local machine. I guess you can use [install_name_tool](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Using-install-name-tool-on-OSX-to-change-DylIb-path-td2338157.html)
utility to change the path of libBLAS.dylib to that of anacondas on run-time.